# What's the difference between `Reals` and `Coq.Reals.*` in Coq?

Tags: coq, real-number

In proving general facts like inequalities and polynomial equations, what's the difference between importing `Reals` and things like `Coq.Reals.{Rineq, R_sqrt, ...}`?

I started from searching specific facts/theorems and ended up in using the latter, but I've seen others using just `Reals`. Is it easier or more comprehensive to just use `Reals`?

Suspecting it's a legacy thing, I tried to import just `Coq.Reals` but it does not seem to exist (Coq 8.5 beta 3).

Comment: Note that `Require RIneq` works too (for backwards compatibility, I suppose). However using unambiguous (extended) paths allows you to define your own `MyProject.RIneq` if you find that there are some derived facts you use a lot but are lacking in the standard library. A few years ago, we used to have this problem and [resorted to awful names](https://github.com/coqtail/coqtail/blob/master/src/mytheories/myReals/MyRIneq.v) but we could have a nicer naming convention now that the stdlib has been refactored. :)

Comment: The fact that the modules in `Coq.Reals.*` always feature an `R` (`Raxioms`, `Rdefinitions`, `Rbase`, `RIneq`, etc.) is also an artefact of these olden days where they were not in `Coq.Reals.*` but rather "at the top-level".